# how can i extract arrays from one array & convert them in object and put them in a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Imagine you have this :

```
[[{id: 1}], [{id: 2}]]
```

Is posible to convert the previous array in something like this? :

`[{id:1}, {id:2}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) for that:

```js
console.log([
  [{
    id: 1
  }],
  [{
    id: 2
  }]
].flat());
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

```js
console.log([[{id: 1}], [{id: 2}]].map(arr => arr[0]))
```

Another way is `Array.prototype.flat()`:

```js
const arr1 = [[{id: 1}], [{id: 2}]]

console.log(arr1.flat())
```